# Best practices to draw on specific parts of image in flutter

Tags: flutter, canvas, flutter-layout, customization

I have an image i want colorize parts of it depending of user reactions should i use previously prepared templates and put on stack and shows them of user reactions or
draw very customized widgets through canvas or what i should do
What is better for performance
What is easily applied

Comment: Like this? (https://pub.dev/packages/painter)

Comment: something like that,lets make it clear through example lets say i want to make path for human body and divide into parts like chest abdomen and legs and colorize chest part when the user click on it do you get it @yellowgray